# Request to server returns a timeout

Tags: yql

I am trying to run the following YQL query:

`select * from xml where url='LinkToMyServer/PerformSomeOperationAndGetXml'`

However, I am getting the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2013-01-03T23:17:06Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
        <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
        <url execution-start-time="1" execution-stop-time="4555"
            execution-time="4554" proxy="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[LinkToMyServer/PerformSomeOperationAndGetXml]]></url>
        <user-time>4555</user-time>
        <service-time>4554</service-time>
        <build-version>32943</build-version>
    </diagnostics> 
    <results/>
</query>
```

Is there any way to increase the timeout somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to increase the YQL request timeout. The only documentation I found related to this - [Paging and Table Limits](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/paging.html) - mentions a 30 second overall time limit for a YQL statement, but doesn't specifically mention the request time.

For a comparison test, I tried `select * from xml where url='http://blackhole.webpagetest.org'` and got similar results as yours - YQL timeout just under 5 seconds with empty results set.

If you can't get your server response time down to under 5 seconds, you may need to find a different solution.